# Why am I getting an Internal JSON-RPC error for calling one state variable from my contract but not on another very similar variable?

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, vyper, frontend

I am using ethers.js in Svelte to communicate with my Vyper contract currently deployed to the Avalanche FUJI testnet for a basic social networking app. When I call this state variable from my contract:

```
posts: public(HashMap[uint256, Post])
```

using this function:

```
const retrievePosts = async () => {
    posts = await contract.posts(1);
    console.log(posts);
};
```

everything works as it should, but when I call this variable:

```
postCount: public(uint256)
```

using this function:

```
  const retrievePostCount = async () => {
    let postCount = await contract.postCount();
    console.log(postCount);
  };
```

I get this error:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. {code: -32603, message: 'Internal JSON-RPC error.', data: {…}}
```

I have looked at many different threads on this error but none of them seem to apply to this situation. I've also read the ethers.js docs sections on calling contract functions but can't find anything I'm clearly doing wrong.

NOTE: I have these two functions separated and simplified to console.logs to identify the source of the error, which is for some reason in the postCount variable but not the posts one. Also, I already have the address, ABI, provider, signer, and contract defined and working as they should outside of these functions.

Comment: Do the contract implement postCount? Is the abi correct?

Comment: @Ismael I implement postCount in the initialization function:                                              `@external
def __init__():
    self.postCount = 0`                                                                                                      and it returns the correct value in the tests. Here's its abi section: `{ "gas": 1238, "inputs": [], "name": "postCount", "outputs": [  {  "name": "",  "type": "uint256" }  ], "stateMutability": "view",  "type": "function"  }`